# Creating a an empty dataframe with individual column type set to float

Tags: pandas, dataframe, casting

I am creating the columns for an empty dataframe and need to set a particular column (Room #) to float:

```
columns = ['Time','Name','Company','Room #', 'etc'] # all type object
df["Room #"] = (df["Room #"]).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

However when I check the types at this point, it is int64 instead of the desired float:

```
df.infer_objects().dtypes
Time                                    object
Name                                    object
Company                                 object
Room #                                   int64
etc                                     object
```

I don't want to create this as a dictionary because the actual data is fed to the frame later.
What is the correct method to coerce the Room # into a float type for that column only?

Comment: add `.astype(float)`

Comment: FWIW, note that creating an empty DataFrame to fill it later is most often inefficient

Comment: I appreciate it isn't the most efficient, yes. I may still consider a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
columns = ['Time','Name','Company','Room #', 'etc'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns).astype({'Room #': float})

print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
Time        object
Name        object
Company     object
Room #     float64
etc         object
dtype: object
```

Or, using your method, force the dtype with `downcast='float'`:

```
columns = ['Time','Name','Company','Room #', 'etc'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

df['Room #'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Room #'], errors='coerce', downcast='float')

print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
Time        object
Name        object
Company     object
Room #     float32
etc         object
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, that syntax works. It's casting it as a float32 though and I specifically want a float64

Comment: df["Room #"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Room #"], errors='coerce', downcast='float').astype('float64')

Comment: @MaxRussell then `pd.DataFrame(columns=columns).astype({'Room #': 'float64'})` ;)

Comment: What would be the best method of applying the format to multiple (but not all) columns?

Comment: With a dictionary: `pd.DataFrame(columns=columns).astype({'col1': 'float64', 'col2': 'float64'})` or if many: `pd.DataFrame(columns=columns).astype(dict.fromkeys(['col1', 'col2', 'col4'], 'float64'))`

Comment: can they be done by the column indices?

Comment: Sure `.astype(dict.fromkeys(df.columns[[1, 2, 4]], 'float64'))`

Comment: but can I apply it from list indices?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, maybe ask a new question with all the details