# Creating dataframe from dictionary with multiple dtypes set for columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, dtype

I would like to create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary but set multiple dtypes on selected columns at creation. EDIT - should have made this clear - I have already created the dictionary and have passed it in as col_dets in this example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(col_dets, index=[0]).astype(dict.fromkeys(df.columns[[3, 6, 9]], 'float64'))
```

I am aware the above is incorrect, but is there a method to do this? Ideally stating columns at these indices are float64 and at other indices are int64 (for example?)

Comment: what is `col_dets` and can you explain **how** you want the dtypes to be different?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197774/assign-pandas-dataframe-column-dtypes

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462257/create-empty-dataframe-in-pandas-specifying-column-types

Comment: @MilosStojanovic I believe the question is how to change the dtype based on position (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78074140/creating-a-an-empty-dataframe-with-individual-column-type-set-to-float#comment137640932_78074150) to my answer to their previous question)

Comment: @mozway *create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary but set multiple dtypes on selected columns at creation* this is what I was following

Comment: @MilosStojanovic I know the question is unclear, which is why I asked OP to make it explicit, I can guess what is expected since I answered their previous question ;)

Comment: col_dets is dictionary. Index on 0 (which is always Time in my data). The varying columns should be majority object but I have a number which are float64 and also a number which are int64. I'd additionally like to be able to assign ranges of indices to a type, because there are blocks of same type grouped across the columns & also because I've got 50+ columns of data and a more concise method of passing in each index required would be really nice.

Comment: det_cols itself is built from a list of columns (headers) and a list of details. I should point out that I'm implementing this stuff to scrape from a page in Robot Framework. I guess when creating the DF I should also set the columns value as that particular list

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a follow-up of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78074140/16343464) and that you want to assign a different type **based on column position**, you could use:

```
dtypes = {3: 'float32', 6: 'float64', 9: 'complex64'}

df = df.astype(dict(zip(df.columns[list(dtypes)], dtypes.values())))

print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
col0       object
col1       object
col2       object
col3      float32
col4       object
col5       object
col6      float64
col7       object
col8       object
col9    complex64
dtype: object
```

Used input:

```
col_dets = [f'col{i}' for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_dets, index=[0])
```

Comment: In this case, I need to assign the types to the columns. There are 50+ columns so ideally being able to assign individual indices AND ranges of columns as an argument to one type or the other (I think I'm only needing 2 or 3 int64 in the data)

Comment: @MaxRussell as explained before, **be explicit**. All that is possible but this saves everyone's time if you clearly explain what you want from the beginning, with a clear example of the data and expected behavior.